# How to perform the $p$ test for integral convergence

Tags: integration, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{x}$ to see if it converges or not with the $p$-test.

This is what I have so far :

$L = \lim_{x\to\infty}$ = $\frac{\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^p}}$ solving this I get $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ = $\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^{1-p}}$

Then I make a distinction between $1-p > 0$ and $1 - p < 0$ for these I get that when $p > 1$ this limit tends to infinity and when $p < 1$ the limit tends to 0.

Now, my problem is that I am not sure how I am supposed to make a conclusion about the convergence. I know that if the limit is $0$ that $\frac{1}{x^p}$ is greater than $\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x}$ and the contrary is true when the limit is $\infty$. From there I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Can someone please help out?

Comment: Well, you cannot use the $p$-test here to conclude because the integrand is oscillating. If you take the absolute value of the integrand, then the new integral will not converge, so you cannot draw any conclusion from this. In fact, $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{n}x}{x^p}dx$ converges for every positive integer $n$ and $p>0$ from the Dirichlet test. You can show the Dirichlet test holds using integration by parts if you want.

Comment: @mertunsal Can I then use the p-test for any other continuous function that is not periodic?

Comment: It has nothing to do with periodicity. $p$-test is a bit weak to deduce convergence or divergence for lots of cases that's why you need some other tools to show these.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the convergence of this integral you can use Dirichlet's test. \begin{equation}f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\ decreasing\ on\ [1,+\infty)\ and\ tends\ to\ 0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}g(x)=sin^3(x)\ has\ limited\ integral\ on\ [1,+\infty)\end{equation}
\begin{equation}(\int sin^3(x)dx=\frac{cos^3(x)}{3}-cos(x)+C)\end{equation}
These two imply that:
\begin{equation} \int_1^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx\ converges\end{equation}
The Dirichlet test is very useful when it comes to these types of integrals.